# What the format of latitude & longitude?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I got sql lite database from client. In that database latitude & longitude are present. I saw lots of format of lat & long but this format i did not understand. The same format is working in iphone app. I dont know how to use this format for Map activity. Please help me regarding this.
Check format which i got in database

```
latitude=5.128.220.813.451.690 longitude=4.842.159.586.816.360
```

some where in database like

```
lat=50.556.213 & long=-96.633.602
```

how to solve this problem. help me.

Answer (score 1):

Check this

http://www.accessgrid.org/node/767

[image]